# python multiprocessing comparison

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I am using multiprocessing for training a neural network where one process construct the batch samples and puts them in a queue and the parent process reads from the queue and trains the network with pytorch.

I noticed that the total time of training using multiprocessing was not shorter than using a single process, and when investigating further, I discovered that although reading from the queue in the multiprocess is faster than constructing the queue in the single process (as expected), the process of training (which is the same code for both multiprocessing and single processing) takes longer in the multiprocess.

I made up a simple script exemplifying. See script below:

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import numpy as np
import time

n = 200

def get_sample():
    local_loop = 400
    # data
    x = np.random.rand(n,n)
    p = np.random.rand(n,n)
    y = 0
    for i in range(local_loop):
        y += np.power(x, p)
    return y

def new_process(q_data, total_loops):
    for i in range(total_loops):
        q_data.put(get_sample())
    print('finish new process')

def main(multi_proc=False):
    st = time.time()
    total_loops = 100
    
    local_loop = 2500
    mt = 0
    other_t = 0

    st_multi = time.time()
    if multi_proc:
        q_data = mp.Queue()
        new_proc = mp.Process(target=new_process,args=(q_data, total_loops))
        new_proc.start()
    mt += time.time() - st_multi

    for i in range(total_loops):
        st_multi = time.time()
        if multi_proc:
            y = q_data.get()
        else:
            y = get_sample()
        mt += time.time() - st_multi

        other_st = time.time()
        for j in range(local_loop):
            y += np.random.rand(n,n)
        other_t += time.time() - other_st

    st_multi = time.time()
    if multi_proc:
        assert q_data.empty()
        new_proc.join()
    mt += time.time() - st_multi

    print('\nmulti_proc', multi_proc)
    print('multi_proc_time', mt)
    print('other_time', other_t)

    print(f'total time: {time.time()-st}')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main(multi_proc=False)
    main(multi_proc=True)
```

When I run it, I get the result:

```
multi_proc False
multi_proc_time 36.44150114059448
other_time 39.08155846595764
total time: 75.5232412815094
finish new process

multi_proc True
multi_proc_time 0.4313678741455078
other_time 40.54900646209717
total time: 40.980711460113525
```

`other_time` is more than 1 second longer when multi_process=True (when they should be the same). This seems to be consistent across platforms/multiple experiments and in my real example it is longer than the gain from using multiprocessing, which is causing a big problem.

Any hint of what is happening?

Comment: I can't reproduce this (using `time.perf_counter()` rather than the inaccurate `time.time()`): with mp=False, other_time = 27.13; with mp=True, 27.173.

Comment: Anyway, remember that you will need to pay (in terms of time) a serialization/deserialization "tax" for each object you transfer between processes.

Comment: I refactored things a bit (and lowered some of the numbers because I'm impatient): https://gist.github.com/akx/b7e1e833e37f71017bd7440fdef1d60d On my machine there's no discernible difference in "local" time between the two.

Comment: I'd like to point out that the performance of multiprocessing depends on the OS, and it's slightly faster on linux than on windows, like parts of the second faster.

Comment: @AhmedAEK OP is noticing a performance difference in the "other time", which is _not_ multiprocessing-related.

Comment: That could also be the cpu thermals, the multiprocessing work can trigger thermal throttling on some machines (or like almost all intel consumer CPUs)

Comment: just to prove it is indeed thermal throttling, i used an old laptop that had bad thermal design, and worked it with turbo mode and hyperthreading both on vs off, when the laptop was working in potato mode (therefore no thermal issues) both times were exactly equal, but when working it in turbo mode, the time for the multiprocessed code "other" is 2.5 seconds longer.

Comment: Good catch. I kept an eye on my machine's throttling while testing this, and it remained at 100%.

Comment: @AKK Thanks for the refactoring. I tested your code (slight refactor since I don't have hyperfine) with my mac M1 2020, and in a raspberry pi 4. In both cases results show that multiprocessing has worse other_time performance. In my real problem, the sub process is idle most of the time, so it might be thermal throttling but i'm wondering if termal throttling would happen with such a simple example with a mac M1. M1 results for 5 runs: Comparison mp false other_time: 8.32 mp true other_time 9.06

Comment: Sorry, results above were for Rpi4. For M1 after 10 runs: Comparison mp false: 1.49 mp true 1.55. I also checked and M1 is not being throttled.

Comment: Curious. I don't know what to tell you though, since I can't repro this. (Macbook 2019, 2.4 Ghz i9 CPU, Python 3.10.6.)

Comment: @AKX if you do more runs (say 10 or 20) and take averages of other_time, do you see a difference?

Comment: @Guillermo Not really: https://gist.github.com/akx/a2813475c0879a9a0321af33cf2ce63b

Comment: @AKX can you average over local dur? I can only see see the total time average, which is expected to be different from using multiprocessing, but not local dur average

Comment: The average of `local dur`: single = 2.129, multi = 2.176.

Comment: Some difference (almost 2-3%). If you increase ```LOCAL_ITERS```  to 1000, and do maybe 20 runs, what do you get? Really appreciate the effort btw :)

Comment: With `LOCAL_ITERS=1000`, the average local dur is 4.4819 without multi and 4.716 with multi. 'python3 so73815479.py multi' ran 1.43 ± 0.09 times faster than 'python3 so73815479.py'.

Comment: @AKX there you go, there is a 5% performance difference in the non multiprocessing part of the code with this simple example. If it is not throttling, what is the reason?

Comment: I don't know. :) I turned the "CPU turbo boost" feature off, so it's scaling frequencies less aggressively, and I'm getting average local dur 7.536 for single and 7.594 multi...

Comment: It seems that numpy by default is multithreading and having the parent process running then concurs for the threads. https://brianzhang01.github.io/2020/02/on-numpy-multithreading/ Could this explain the difference?

Answer (score 0):

Your results are what I would expect. But is your benchmark a true representation of reality?

In the multiprocessing case you have 2 processes:

1. The main process, which creates "batch samples" and retrieves results generated by a child process.
2. A `get_sample` child process that gets the sample created by the main process and puts a result to a queue for the main process to retrieve.

Both processes are running in parallel but the main process described above is very trivial requiring very little CPU processing compared to the child process. So any gains you achieve by running both processes in parallel are defeated by the additional overhead required in moving samples and results from one address space to another.

But what if creating a new batch sample were not so trivial? In the revamped benchmark below, I am ensuring that we spin some CPU cycles in producing a new sample by calling `spin_cycles`. I have arranged things so that the code for the multiprocessing benchmark and sequential processing benchmark are kept separate for clarity:

```py
import multiprocessing as mp
import numpy as np
import time

n = 200
total_loops = 20
local_loops = 400

def spin_cycles():
    # simulate real processing time:
    x = 0
    for i in range(10_000_000):
        x += i * i
    return x

########### Sequential Benchmark: #######################

def process_sequential(sample):
    # data
    x = np.random.rand(n,n)
    p = np.random.rand(n,n)
    y = 0
    for i in range(local_loops):
        y += np.power(x, p)
    return y

def sequential_processing():
    results = []
    for sample in range(total_loops):
        # simulate real processing time:
        spin_cycles()
        results.append(process_sequential(sample))

def main_sequential():
    st = time.time()
    results = sequential_processing()
    et = time.time()
    print('Sequential time:', et-st)

########## Multiprocessing Benchmark ################

def process_multi(in_q, out_q):
    for _ in range(total_loops):
        sample = in_q.get()
        # data
        x = np.random.rand(n,n)
        p = np.random.rand(n,n)
        y = 0
        for i in range(local_loops):
            y += np.power(x, p)
        out_q.put(y)

def construct_batch_samples_multi(in_q):
    for sample in range(total_loops):
        # simulate real processing time:
        spin_cycles()
        in_q.put(sample)

def main_multi():
    st = time.time()
    in_q, out_q = mp.Queue(), mp.Queue()
    p = mp.Process(target=process_multi, args=(in_q, out_q))
    p.start()
    construct_batch_samples_multi(in_q)
    results = [out_q.get() for _ in range(total_loops)]
    et = time.time()
    p.join()
    print('Multiprocessing time:', et-st)

########### Run Benchmarks #######################
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main_multi()
    main_sequential()
```

Prints:

```None
Multiprocessing time: 18.932964086532593
Sequential time: 28.5939993858337
```

**Update**

This is to demonstrate that the time to actually process a sample is identical for the multiprocessing and sequential benchmarks. Specifically, I am measuring in the multiprocessing case the total time processing samples not including the time to read and write to queues for a more direct comparison with the sequential processing case. I have also used `time.process_time()` to measure actual CPU time and have removed the call to `spin_cycles` so as to not confuse the issue.

```py
import multiprocessing as mp
import numpy as np
import time

n = 200
total_loops = 20
local_loops = 400

########### Sequential Benchmark: #######################

def sequential_processing():
    results = []
    start_time = time.process_time()
    for sample in range(total_loops):
        # data
        x = np.random.rand(n,n)
        p = np.random.rand(n,n)
        y = 0
        for i in range(local_loops):
            y += np.power(x, p)
        results.append(y)
    processing_time = time.process_time() - start_time
    print("Sequential processing time:", processing_time)
    return results

def main_sequential():
    st = time.time()
    results = sequential_processing()
    et = time.time()
    print('Total elapsed time:', et-st)

########## Multiprocessing Benchmark ################

def process_multi(q):
    samples = [q.get() for _ in range(total_loops)]
    results = []
    t = time.process_time()
    for sample in samples:
        # data
        x = np.random.rand(n,n)
        p = np.random.rand(n,n)
        y = 0
        for i in range(local_loops):
            y += np.power(x, p)
        results.append(y)
    processing_time = time.process_time() - t
    print('Multiprocessing processing time:', processing_time)
    return results

def construct_batch_samples_multi(q):
    for sample in range(total_loops):
        q.put(sample)

def main_multi():
    st = time.time()
    q  = mp.Queue()
    p = mp.Process(target=construct_batch_samples_multi, args=(q,))
    p.start()
    process_multi(q)
    et = time.time()
    p.join()
    print('Total multiprocessing elapsed time:', et-st)

########### Run Benchmarks #######################
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main_multi()
    main_sequential()
```

Prints:

```None
Multiprocessing processing time: 10.796875
Total multiprocessing elapsed time: 11.060487270355225
Sequential processing time: 10.96875
Total elapsed time: 11.052014112472534
```

There is essentially no difference in the two processing times (in this run the multiprocessing processing was a bit faster).

Comment: This doesn't quite answer OP's question, which was "why is this code that's running in the multiprocessing parent process slower when multiprocessing is enabled".

Comment: I believe I did answer it. Re-read the paragraph above following my bullet points.

Comment: OP originally does _not_ have three processes, but two. One MP child process that generates samples, and the parent process that receives them and processes them.

Comment: My point is still valid: If you had one task that required 20 seconds and a second process that required .001 seconds and you ran them sequentially it would take 20.001 seconds to run. If you ran them in parallel and there was no additional overhead incurred by reading and writing to multiprocessing queues, they would take 20 seconds. This is not much of a gain. BUT: there is overhead incurred by multiprocessing.

Comment: And why wouldn't the OP want to use a multiprocessing pool? The main process creates samples and for each one creates a new task to be run by the pool so that the pytorch processing can be done in parallel.

Comment: I have updated the answer to reflect that there are only 2 processes.

Comment: Yes, I addressed MP overhead in the second comment of the original post. Please look at the measurement methodology: the curious thing, and the question, here is that **once we already have acquired the data from the MP queue**, subsequent computation in the parent process is slower.

Comment: See my update to the answer. The computation time is the same.

Comment: You aren't measuring the same thing. `process_multi` consumes all samples from the queue first before processing anything locally, OP's (or mine, in the comments) doesn't.

Comment: **As I have been saying it takes time to read (and to write) to a multiprocessing queue.  So if you add back in the queue reading time, multiprocessing will take longer due to this is additional overhead you don't have in sequential processing. The second coded example shows that the processing time of samples not including the queue access time is the same as for sequential processing. The first coded example shows how total multiprocessing time will be an improvement if we assume that generating the samples is expensive and we overlap that with the processing of samples.**

Comment: @Booboo thanks for your code. I think though we are not measuring the same thing, given that you consume all the elements of the queue in the second example and afterwards time the remaining process. This would mean that the child process probably shuts down earlier than in my example, which I would definitely expect to have equal performance.